# How do I know MAM data has been published?

Tags: iota-network, tangle, masked-authenticated-messaging

I am running a code to publish random data on Tangle via MAM. If I don't fetch the data at the same time, and I just want to confirm if it has been published on Tangle, how do I do that?

Also, is it possible to fetch the data that I published previously?

I am running this sample program using a Devnet node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just run `Mam.fetch`. You need to store the `root` somewhere, and the sideKey if you are using “restricted” mode.

Answer (score 1):

What library do you use? You can check, if the transaction is referenced by a milestone. This is the ultimate confirmation for your transaction. If the milestone directly or indirectly confirms your transaction, the transaction is received by all full-nodes.

Comment: I am using node.js for libraries for MAM script. How will I check with this?